# Get 404 error when accessing a public file's meta data on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a file which is shared public.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SuYrjwWJKlNmSEr6CpcOVFUT1MpGqLe3/view
```

But when I use Google API to access the file's meta data, the result is 404 not found.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1SuYrjwWJKlNmSEr6CpcOVFUT1MpGqLe3
```

Can someone tell me the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access via Drive API a file that is not located on your Drive, you need to set

`supportsAllDrives` to `true`:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221SuYrjwWJKlNmSEr6CpcOVFUT1MpGqLe3%22%2C%22supportsAllDrives%22%3Atrue%7D

Comment: This file is public shared so its metadata should be public as well. I tried other public files and do not get 404 error.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your initial queston, I update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just found the add comment button today. Sorry for the late response.